# c - how logical expression 2 > -3 calculate in gcc

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, gdb, logical-operators

Let's say i have this file:

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai done_read]$ cat my_bool.c 
#include <stdio.h>
int
main() {
        if (2 > -3) {
                printf("true\n" );
        }
        else  {
                printf("false\n" );
        }
}

[xiaobai@xiaobai done_read]$
```

Compile and debug with gdb:

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai done_read]$ gcc -g3 my_bool.c     
[xiaobai@xiaobai done_read]$ gdb ./a.out
GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora 7.8.2-39.fc21
...
Reading symbols from ./a.out...done.
(gdb) b *main+1
+b *main+1
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400537: file my_bool.c, line 3.
(gdb) r
+r
Starting program: .../a.out 

Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000000400537 in main () at my_bool.c:3
3       main() {
(gdb) s
+s
5                       printf("true\n" );
(gdb) s
+s
_IO_puts (str=0x4005e0 "true") at ioputs.c:34
34      {
(gdb)
```

It always skip the `if (2 > -3)` construction and step into `printf("true\n" );`

I want to understand how c behave if 2 > -3 in binary level, how it know 0x2 is larger than 0xfffffffffffffffd whereas 0xfffffffffffffffd is obviously bigger than 0x2. May be it store signed bit or something but it need to check long long maximum size (0x7fffffffffffffff) in my system to know 0xfffffffffffffffd have a signed bit ?

Seems like gdb not possible to do that, so how do i debug this kind of logical expression (`if 2 > -3`) in assembly/binary level ?

**[UPDATE]** Below is my gcc configuration options, installed in Fedora 21.

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai note]$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.9.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.9.2-20150212/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.9.2-20150212/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/cloog-install --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 20150212 (Red Hat 4.9.2-6) (GCC) 
[xiaobai@xiaobai note]$
```

**[UPDATE2]** I changed the title because `gdb gcc` is the only way i can think to debug it. But it doesn't really help much to understand how `2 > -3` perform in gcc's fold-constants.c or some other source file. How logical operation perform/involved in this particular case ? How gcc detect sign bit before perform logical operation ?

Comment: The compiler *knows* that `2` will always be larger than `-3` so it can optimize away the whole condition (and the other branch) completely. Try compiling with the `-O0` flag, it tells GCC to not optimize at all, I don't know if it will stop the [constant folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) of that simple expression though.

Comment: I did -O0, but this is default option described in gcc manual and still the same.

Comment: As for how `0x00000002` can be larger than `0xfffffffd`, read and learn about [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

Comment: After searching a little, it seems that constant folding can't be disabled in GCC, so you're out of luck as long as you use literal values. Try declaring and using variables instead, maybe marked as `volatile`.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings and pay heed to them! gcc should already complain the `else` path is unreachable.

Comment: use variables that the compiler can't optimize.  specifically: volatile int two = 2; volatile int negThree = -3; if ( two > negThree ) ...  You shouldn't need the 'volatile' keyword if you use -O0, but otherwise volatile variables must always be fetched from memory so they can't be optimized away.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I found gcc source code fold-const.c but look like it's hard to understand in my noob level.

Comment: @Olaf How to enable warnings you're described ? i tried every possible warning i can imagine, i.e `gcc  -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c89 -pedantic -O0 -pedantic-errors  -Winit-self -Wuninitialized -Wmissing-declarations -Winit-self -g3 my_bool.c` but no warning.

Comment: Hmm, I was sure gcc will warn about such an always true constant expression and/or the else path being unreachable (it obviously does know both, as it apparently optimises accordingly). Which gcc version do you use? Newer versions often warn about more problems than older.

Comment: @Olaf gcc version 4.9.2 20150212 (Red Hat 4.9.2-6) in Fedora 21.

Comment: Not a real problem. You don't need tools to understand `2 > -3`. But let's pretend you desperately need a debugger. Suppose you have convinced gdb to stop at the line that contains the boolean expression. How would it help you do something you couldn't do before?

Answer (score 1):

I figure the actual question is "I want to understand how c behave if 2 > -3 in binary level". To find this out, you can observe machine code created by the compiler.

Following command should create assembly code in a human readable form, according to http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/v2faq/faq8_20.html:

```
gcc -S foo.c
```

To find out how each assembly command is handled by the CPU at the binary level, you should read the manual of your CPU.

Comment: But the problem is gcc fold the expression before translate into assembly code, produced  `movl    $.LC0, %edi ` in which `.LC0:` is `.string "true"`. I think the only way to understand is `gdb gcc` to step in the gcc's fold-const.c's `if (TREE_CODE (arg1) == INTEGER_CST && TREE_CODE (arg0) != INTEGER_CST) part. It's too hard to me. i just hope there's someone compiler expert can give a brief tour for this particular case. Will gcc detect sign bit based on current system maximum size ? How two complement calculate(not just common theory, but how gcc perform)? Which logical operation involved ?

Comment: As far as I understand, gcc should without optimization create a comparison of two signed integers. Assembly code would save those two integers to registers, and compare them. Comparison would be done with jg command, which performs signed comparison at CPU level. So your question is not about gcc, or about debugging. It is about how comparison of signed integers is handled at CPU level. I cannot answer that. You probably should make a new question in which you clearly define what you want to know,

Answer (score 0):

Because `(2 > -3)` is a constant expression, gdb optimizes it away.  If you use variables instead, that won't happen:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i=2, j=-3;
    if (i > j) {
            printf("true\n" );
    }
    else  {
            printf("false\n" );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

gdb output:

```
[dbush] gdb /tmp/x1
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.0.1-45.el5)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /tmp/x1...done.
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x4004a0: file /tmp/x1.c, line 4.
Starting program: /tmp/x1
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x2aaaaaaab000

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at /tmp/x1.c:4
4           int i=2, j=-3;
(gdb) step
5               if (i > j) {
(gdb)
6                       printf("true\n" );
(gdb)
true
11      }
(gdb)
```

EDIT:

Regarding how `(i > j)` is evaluated, signed integer comparison is done differently from unsigned.  From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement):

> Comparison is often implemented with a dummy subtraction, where the
>   flags in the computer's status register are checked, but the main
>   result is ignored. The zero flag indicates if two values compared
>   equal. If the exclusive-or of the sign and overflow flags is 1, the
>   subtraction result was less than zero, otherwise the result was zero
>   or greater. These checks are often implemented in computers in
>   conditional branch instructions.
>
> Unsigned binary numbers can be ordered by a simple lexicographic
>   ordering, where the bit value 0 is defined as less than the bit value
>   1. For two's complement values, the meaning of the most significant bit is reversed (i.e. 1 is less than 0).

Comment: Sorry for inconvenient but I just updated my question. How i > j be calculated in gcc internal ?